# Drawing video frame on html5 canvas in Chrome Mobile with invisible video tag

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, chrome-for-android

I have a problem with HTML5 video and canvas on Android (Chrome for Android). I draw frames from video to canvas (using CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()). It works fine in desktop browsers, but not in Chrome for Android. In Chrome for android it works only if video element visible. I mean it really visible: even if element visible by properties but not visible due to page scroll - it doesn't work.

This example http://html5demos.com/video-canvas works only if mobile device viewport shows at least 1 pixel of video element. If video element fully hidden - canvas doesn't update.

So, I'm looking for workaround. How to make canvas update when video element is invisible?

Comment: Fun Fact: This also happens on Mac desktop Safari in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these CSS styles on your video element:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
```

That way it will always be "visible" in the page, regardless of scrolling, and it won't take up any space, but you just won't see it.

This sounds like a bug, or at least a non-standard behavior, so setting opacity to 0 may not work. You could try setting opacity to something very low like 0.05, which might not be so bad, especially if it's only 1x1 pixel.

Comment: opacity:0 is not working, you're right. My style for video element now: 'position': 'fixed',
            'z-index': 8000000000,
            'left': 0,
            'top': 0,
            'width': '1px',
            'height': '1px',
            'opacity': '0.00000001',
            'pointer-events': 'none'[/code]

Comment: Why do you need a high z-index?

Comment: It's exactly for my page only. It needs, because much elements creates dynamicly, and there is possibility that video will be hidden by others element.

Comment: Better to limit `z-index` to max of signed 32-bit integer `2147483647` and to limit the precision of opacity to `0.001` (practically transparent, it's good enough) or `0.0001` (if you want to be extra sure) as some browsers like Safari seem to round higher precision like `0.0000001` and longer to a flat `0`.

Answer (score 0):

yes，I also met this same problem.I set video display:none or hide it by position, but some browsers can't grasp screen，for example： ios 11 safari，chrome 67 in win 10. So I set opacity:0.000001, I check pointer-events property compatibility， and I am not sure this method will work in most of browsers supporting getUserMedia. Ps, this behavior due to browsers security policy, after all some properties are not rules.